# Increment +1 for large data points with different spacings

Tags: excel

I am not very competent in Excel so please bear with me. I would like to have the the numbers in the bottom (54, 55, 56, 57,...,288) to be replaced by (369, 370, 371, 372,...,656) respectively. Sometimes spacing of these numbers is more than 4 so the =cell+1 did not work. I have 1500 rows and until 288, so actually 288+368=656. Any easy way to do this rather than doing it manually, which will take ages?

[image: Actual data]

Comment: so every 5th row incement 1+ the row 5 before it?

Comment: I would like to replace the 56,57,etc. by 369,370,371,etc. Thing is it is not necessarily the fifth row so sometimes it is fourth and sometimes fifth. Any way around that?

Comment: You would need to use VBA to replace the numbers.  If you want the new numbers in a different column then it can be done with formulas.

Comment: Put this formula in the column/row to the right of 54 and fill down to your last row. Then copy cells starting at the row where 54 but now shows 368.  right click on where 54 is now and past special (values) then delete the column we added to the right  `=IF(D6<>"",314+D6,"")`  This assumes 54...55...56...57 is growth by 1 each time.

Comment: @ScottCraner I looked into VBA, seems difficult to learn and I'm short on time!

Comment: @xQbert Wow!! That's exactly what I needed. Thanks so much! It worked for me :)

Comment: Alternatively; set a filter on the range, deselect blanks, then paste a formula to sum the previous seven(say) rows +1 in the cells from the "54" onwards. For example if "54" is in D250 the formula that goes in there is `=SUM(D243:D249)+1` - then you can just paste that into non-blank cells. Then clean up by clearing the filter, copying and pasting-values into the whole column.